# What happens when a Dispatcher created on a background thread is not shutdown? How to make sure that a dispatcher is properly shut down?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, multithreading, mfc

The following is one of the remarks on Dispatcher class.

> If you create a Dispatcher on a background thread, be sure to shut down the dispatcher before exiting the thread.

What are the consequences if one fails to invoke shut down on a dispatcher created on a background thread?

I have an MFC application which creates a WPF window on a background thread.  Consequently, a dispatcher is created.  When I close the WPF window first, I get to explicitly invoke shutdown on the dispatcher, but when I close the MFC application, the WPF window closes along.

It seems the dispatcher is being shut down implicitly, or the thread is being aborted.  Which is it?

Update:

The following method creates a new thread and opens the wpf window.

```
public void ShowWindow(SomeObject someObject)
{
    System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread((tuple) =>
        {
            Tuple<Dispatcher, SomeObject> data = tuple as Tuple<Dispatcher, SomeObject>;
            Window window = new WPFWindow(data.Item1, data.Item2);
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            this.tmp = 0;
        });
    thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start(new Tuple<Dispatcher, SomeObject>(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, someObject));
}
```

So, I put a break along the statement "this.tmp = 0;" and it doesn't get hit when I close the MFC application.  Is it safe to assume that the Dispatcher is not being shutdown, but the thread is being aborted?

If the thread is aborted, what are the consequences?

Update:

On another project, I ran into a problem where the GC doesn't seem to be doing its job.  It turns out, it's related to a Dispatcher started on a background thread that is not being shutdown.  The WPF application's memory usage just kept increasing every time a task is ran on background thread.  So, be sure to invoke shutdown on Dispatchers created on a background thread whether you created a Dispatcher object explicitly or not.

Not invoking shutdown on Dispatcher created on background thread will cause memory/resource leak.  Dispatcher objects hang onto resources.  Hence, the GC aren't able to clean them up.

To make sure that a dispatcher is shut down properly, in my case, I have to spawn the background thread from the MFC side of the application then have the main thread wait on it before it completely shuts down.  As Hans Passant pointed out, MFC doesn't wait unless it is explicitly told.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `return` statement of you background thread and see if it gets hit.

Comment: Allowing the main thread of an MFC app to terminate without explicitly waiting for that worker thread to complete will always terminate the entire process.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Hans.  That puts me in the right direction to how I can properly invoke shutdown on the dispatcher when MFC is about to exit.  However, I'm still curious what the consequences are if a Dispatcher is not shutdown explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't shutdown dispatcher, thread will stuck in message loop and don't exit

Comment: That is true especially with regards to the sample code I posted, but I was more concern about the less obvious side effects.  In the problem I encountered, I didn't make a call to Dispatcher.Run(), and some time during the thread execution (not very obvious) a dispatcher object allocated resources.  Not invoking shutdown on that thread's dispatcher caused the dispatcher object to hang onto resources and never garbage-collected.

Comment: I'm still a little curious what happens to an allocated resource when the thread is simply aborted (without invoking shutdown on the Dispatcher).  Right now I'm running with an assumption that the CLR takes care of it, and a rule to always invoke shutdown on Dispatchers created on background threads.

Comment: When you shutdown your application, all background threads are going to be terminated and threads with dispatchers also. If you don't call Dispatcher.Run(), another object could call Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher which forces to create dispatcher if there is no dispatcher for current thread. As for aborting thread, i think when thread is aborted threads stack is destroyed and GC can collect all objects, but not necessarily release all resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the main thread you can do something like

```
Dispatcher.FromThread(thread).InvokeShutDown();
```

However this will cause the 'Dispatcher.Run()' to generate an exception, so you also need to change it to

```
try
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
catch {}
```